# drone.io headless dartium testing

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, dart

Can you run browser based unit tests for Dart on drone.io? my last failed build is [here](https://drone.io/github.com/0xor1/homo_erectus/8). I tried `sudo start xvfb` but I'm not sure how to point that to my index.html file that launches my unit tests, anyone know how to do this? I should say that I am in no way interested in any actual DOM testing but my library imports 'dart:html' so I can't run it in the basic dart vm only configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my Drone script for the [xml2json](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/xml2json) library

```
pub install
sudo start xvfb
content_shell --args --dump-render-tree test/xml2json.html | sed -n 2p | grep PASS
```

It uses standard HTML based unit testing, ie includes htmlconfiguration().

The grep is just to check for pass/fail, you may not need this.

Comment: I tried your script but it failed, if I change it to be `content_shell --args --dump-render-tree test/xml2json.html` then it works fine otherwise I get
`$ content_shell --args --dump-render-tree test/unit/index.html
$ sed -n 2p
$ grep PASS
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0".`

Comment: I get the following failure: `/home/ubuntu/.build.sh: line 52: content_shell: command not found`. How to install the content_shell command?

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**  Modified the build script to download content_shell.  Also updated the path to content_shell in the hop task `createUnitTestTask()`.

---

I use the [hop pub package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/hop) to do headless testing for drone.  You can refer to the [simplot](https://github.com/scribeGriff/simplot) library for a relatively simple example.  But the steps are basically to add the following to your `pubspec.yaml` as developer dependencies:

```
hop: '>=0.27.0'
unittest: '>=0.9.0 <0.10.0'
```

Create a tool directory in your project root and add a file `hop_runner.dart`.  Mine looks something like this:

```
library dumprendertree;

import 'package:hop/hop.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

main(List<String> args) {
  addTask('test', createUnitTestTask());
  runHop(args);
}

Task createUnitTestTask() {
  return new Task((TaskContext tcontext) {
    tcontext.info("Running Unit Tests....");
    var result = Process.run('./content_shell',
        ['--dump-render-tree','test/simplot_tests.html'])
        .then((ProcessResult process) {
          tcontext.info(process.stdout);
        });
    return result;
  });
}
```

You can see where it is calling my `simplot_tests.html` file in the test directory.

Then my drone script is:

```
$DART_SDK/../chromium/download_contentshell.sh
unzip content_shell-linux-x64-release.zip
mv drt*/* .
pub get
sudo start xvfb
dart --checked tool/hop_runner.dart test
```

The `simplot_tests.html` file looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Unit Tests for Simplot Library</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/unittest/test_controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <script type="application/dart" src="simplot_tests.dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And finally, the dart file looks something like this:

```
import 'package:simplot/simplot.dart';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:unittest/html_enhanced_config.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:math';

part 'tests/logarithmic_tests.dart';
part 'tests/time_stamp_tests.dart';
part 'tests/axis_configure_tests.dart';
part 'tests/create_single_plot.dart';
part 'tests/create_multiple_plots.dart';
part '../lib/src/axis_config.dart';

void main() {
  print('Running unit tests for simplot library.');
  useHtmlEnhancedConfiguration();
  group('All Tests:', (){
    test('test of logarithmic functions', () => logarithmicTests());
    test('test of time stamp', () => timeStampTests());
    test('test of axis configuration', () => axisConfigTests());
    test('test of creating a single plot', () => createSinglePlot());
    test('test of creating multiple plots', () => createMultiplePlots());
  });
}
```

Hopefully, that should get you started.

Comment: When I run your sample from the root of the project(dart --checked tool/hop_runner.dart test) I get the following error:
test: ProcessException: No such file or directory
        Command: content_shell --dump-render-tree test/simplot_tests.html
Task did not complete - EXCEPTION (81)

Comment: Do you have a simplot_tests.html file in a test directory?  I just ran it locally on my machine and it works fine and also works fine on drone.  I'm just not sure what you mean when you say run your sample.  Ideally you'd want to modify the path in the answer to your own tests.html file.

Comment: I think it may be a problem with content_shell with Mavericks why the sample is not working for me. I'm getting:  Internals of CFAllocator not known; out-of-memory failures via CFAllocator will not result in termination. http://crbug.com/45650.

Comment: @basheps - It seems that the content-shell executable is no longer included in the Dart SDK starting at 0.8.10.8_r30039.  This causes the error you are seeing (and which I now get also).  Add since Drone no longer has access to content-shell either, it will fail there as well.  If you are interested in using this approach on Drone, you can upvote the request [here](https://drone.uservoice.com/forums/176976-feedback-for-drone-io/suggestions/4933081-download-content-shell-automatically-for-dart-pr).